# nginx and tomcat in eclipse - multiple apps

Tags: nginx, tomcat, eclipse

I'm running Tomcat with Nginx as a load balancer. And too keep all the redirects etc consistent, I am also running it in front of Eclipse.

Tomcat in Eclipse seems to fail it you try to configure multiple virtual hosts. So I need to configure each app to run from a different url in Eclipse. e.g. the `server.xml` looks like:

```
  <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
    <Context docBase="app1" path="/" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:app1"/>
    <Context docBase="app2" path="/app2" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:app2"/>
  </Host>
```

Problem is when I proxy to it, I can't get it to use the code in the subfolder `app2`. It serves it from the root. And I can't seem to get a rewrite to fix it either...

Nginx config has...

```
location ~ \.(do|jsp)$ {
    #rewrite ^(.*) $1 break;
    proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

What I want to do is:

```
    proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2;
```

But that's not allowed it seems.

I know how to fig it with a server. But Eclipse seems to only work with a single virtual host. So I'm stuck with folders...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) ?

> ```
> Syntax:  proxy_pass URL;
> Default: —
> Context: location, if in location, limit_except
> ```
>
> Sets the protocol and address of a proxied server and an optional URI to which a location should be mapped. As a protocol, “http” or “https” can be specified. The address can be specified as a domain name or IP address, and an optional port:
>
> ```
> proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/uri/;
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> In some cases, the part of a request URI to be replaced cannot be determined:
>
> **When location is specified using a regular expression**.
>   In this case, the directive should be specified without a URI.
>
> **When the URI is changed inside a proxied location using the rewrite directive**, and this same configuration will be used to process a request (break) :
>
> ```
> location /name/ {
>     rewrite    /name/([^/]+) /users?name=$1 break;
>     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
> }
> ```
>
> In this case, the URI specified in the directive is ignored and the full changed request URI is passed to the server.
>
> [ ...]